# Drawing using textureRegion

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I'm trying to make a movable car in java, using libgdx and box2d;
I made a car, m_car, with position set in middle of the car.
In every step, i take take the current position of the m_car, decrese that values with the cars width/height, so i have the left bottom corner. When is on a straight ground, it shows well, the texture is where is should be, but when the ground have an angle, the texture position its under, or upper the car.
I don't understand how TextureRegion works, i think that when the angle is not 0, i dont take the point of drawing well, and i dont know how to solve it. help me pls :)
Ty.

Edit:

my code is a mess, its not an actual project, its an ideea, and i took pieces, and put them down to see how they work, so when il start the project, i would know what to do, this is my car declaration:

```
private void car2(){
    m_hz = 5.0f;
    m_zeta = 0.7f;
    m_speed = 50.0f;
    BodyDef bd = new BodyDef();
    bd.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    part1(bd);
    part2(bd);
    part3(bd);
    wheels(bd);
    m_car.setAwake(true);
}

private void part3(BodyDef bd) {
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(0.01f, 0.35f,new Vector2(1.01f - 3, 4.85f - 4), 0);
    m_car.createFixture(shape, 1.0f);
}

private void part1(BodyDef bd){
    PolygonShape chassis = new PolygonShape();
    Vector2 vertices[] = new Vector2[6];
    vertices[0] = new Vector2(-2, -0.5f);
    vertices[1] = new Vector2(-2, 0.5f);
    vertices[2] = new Vector2(1.25f, 0.5f);
    vertices[3] = new Vector2(2.5f, 0.15f);
    vertices[4] = new Vector2(2.5f, -0.5f);
    vertices[5] = new Vector2(-2, -0.5f);

    chassis.set(vertices);
    bd.position.set(new Vector2(3, 4));
    m_car = m_world.createBody(bd);
    m_car.createFixture(chassis, 1.0f);
}

private void part2(BodyDef bd){
    PolygonShape chassis = new PolygonShape();
    Vector2 vertices[] = new Vector2[5];
    vertices[0] = new Vector2(3, 4.5f);
    vertices[1] = new Vector2(3, 5.25f);
    vertices[2] = new Vector2(3.80f, 5.25f);
    vertices[3] = new Vector2(4.25f, 4.5f);
    vertices[4] = new Vector2(3, 4.5f);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i){
        vertices[i].x -= 3;
        vertices[i].y -= 4;
    }
    chassis.set(vertices);
    //m_car = m_world.createBody(bd);
    m_car.createFixture(chassis, 1.0f);         
}

private void wheels(BodyDef bd){

      CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
      circle.setRadius(0.4f);

      FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
      fd.shape = circle;
      fd.density = 1.0f;
      fd.friction = 0.9f;

      bd.position.set(2f, 3.5f);
      m_wheel1 = m_world.createBody(bd);
      m_wheel1.createFixture(fd);

      bd.position.set(4.5f, 3.5f);
      m_wheel2 = m_world.createBody(bd);
      m_wheel2.createFixture(fd);

      WheelJointDef jd = new WheelJointDef();
      Vector2 axis = new Vector2(1.0f, 0.5f);


      jd.initialize(m_car, m_wheel1, m_wheel1.getPosition(), axis);
      jd.motorSpeed = 0.0f;
      jd.maxMotorTorque = 20.0f;
      jd.enableMotor = true;
      jd.frequencyHz = m_hz;
      jd.dampingRatio = m_zeta;
      m_spring1 = (WheelJoint) m_world.createJoint(jd);

      jd.initialize(m_car, m_wheel2, m_wheel2.getPosition(), axis);
      jd.motorSpeed = 0.0f;
      jd.maxMotorTorque = 10.0f;
      jd.enableMotor = false;
      jd.frequencyHz = m_hz;
      jd.dampingRatio = m_zeta;
      m_spring2 = (WheelJoint) m_world.createJoint(jd);     
}
```

some explenation: why i have for for vertices to decreese 3 and 4 ? i didnt know that if i set position to the bodydef, the vertices consider that point to be 0, 0, when i found out, was easyer to me to just decrese (cuz its just for test, to see how it works)

and this is how i draw:

```
 float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(m_car.getAngle());
 batch.draw(textureRegion, x, y, 3f, 4f, 
    4.5f, 2.75f, 1f, 0.61f, angle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a realistic car in Box2D you might find this useful: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/top-down-car

About your problem with the angle: You need to supply the angle of the car to the spriteBatch. TextureRegion doesn't know ANYTHING about where or how it is supposed to be rendered. You need to tell the spriteBatch about those informations.

You can use a Sprite for that. A Sprite can be manipulated with `setRotation(), setPosition()` etc and then being draw with `Sprite.draw(spriteBatch)` instead of `` `spriteBatch.draw(sprite) ``

Furthermore, be careful with your PIXEL_TO_METER conversion and remember to update your Cameras properly.

Comment: ty for info :) im giving the angle to the textureRegion, but not the good position for drawing: this is my problem:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/divt8fbg3jri6go/Untitled4.jpg
the angle is good, pot its bad positioning, and idk why, probably when the angle changes, the position for drawing changes, but idk how it changed, what position i should give

Comment: That looks like it might be a problem with the origin. If the origin of the body/picture is not the same, or not in the middle of the car, the picture might get moved up and down, depending on the angle. But without more code that's just a guess

Comment: The center of the body should be the origin of the texture, which should be the center as well :)

Comment: i edited the question, including the code, the reason i didint gived in the first place, its messy, verry messy and im ashame about that :( if need more, tell me :)

Comment: Sorry, With all those custom numbers I cannot really tell what the problem is. Maybe you should refactor that code a bit and if you are lucky you will find the solution during this process.